# How do I hide a variable from the view?

Tags: objective-c

In objective C, I'm trying to make something hide from view.
Could anyone tell me how to do it by using some sort of
`-(void) something {`?

It's a variable, and I need to make it only appear when a certain variable is true.  I want to know how to make that variable turn invisible all the time to start it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do variable.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare it in the .h file, then it is hidden.

Comment: well, It's a variable, and I need to make it only appear when a certain variable is true.  I want to know how to make that variable turn invisible all the time to start it off.